# How to Integrate Instagram API (Feed) in Laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel-5, instagram-api

I wanna integrate Instagram API in Laravel 5.8.
But I don't know well about it.
So I followed the tutorial "How to Integrate Instagram API (Feed) in Laravel 5.4" of YUTV. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g16aY_SdBfs)
But I made the error. My Laravel project version is 5.8.
If there is a developer who integrates Instagram API in Laravel 5.8, please help me.

1. First install Laravel 5.8
2. Install instagram in Laravel

   Run this command in cmd.

   `$composer require vinkla/instagram 6.0`
3. Create a controller and copy the following code (`InstagramController.php`)

   ```
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use Vinkla\Instagram\Instagram;

   class InstagramController extends Controller
   {
        public function instagramFeed()
       {
            $instagram = new Instagram();
            $instagrams = $instagram->get('bing495989');
            return view('instagram', compact('instagrams'));
        }

   }
   ```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQlpQ.png)

Error: "The user [bing495989] was not found."

why?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the Github page of the package you are using?
https://github.com/vinkla/instagram

The example there looks quite different, the main difference being that you need to provide an access token to the Instagram class constructor method

And I checked out the code and it seems like the package it self is deprecated as the url the request is being sent to doesn't exist (Instagram is removing the old API and moving to Graph API https://www.instagram.com/developer/)

I'd suggest looking for a different package or implementing this yourself.

You can check out Socialite package and check out this post to get started https://quantizd.com/integrating-instagram-api-in-laravel-5-6/